# Active Admin calling original and overriden create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am seeing some odd behaviour when trying to override the create action on an Active Admin resource. My reason for overriding the action is that I want to alter the request params slightly first.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  controller do

    def create
      format_params

      create!
    end

    def update
      format_params

      update!
    end

    def format_params
      params[:user] = ...
    end

  end

end
```

What I am seeing is that *a* create action is being invoked twice - but only on the second time is it my overridden version. By that point, the new record is already created, albeit incorrectly, and the second invoking (which *is* the overridden version) looks like a duplicate resource.

If I empty the custom #create action and leave only a logging statement, I can see that a record is still being created prior to it being invoked, almost as if there is some sort of before_ callback, although I can't find any such thing in the code.

Even more odd - everything works fine on the overridden #update method - the params are altered and the original #update! method delegated to correctly.

I am using Active Admin 0.5.1 on Rails 3.2.13

Cheers

Comment: Did you try 5.0 version of Active Admin?

Comment: Hey. Just tried. Unfortunately there were some view errors which made it difficult to get into the app using that version (I assume you mean 0.5.0). Was there a reason for thinking that the version might be related to this? If so, I'll persevere through the errors. Thanks.